# How do you make ticklabels for chart start with the Monday of each week?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to show a trend over time based on progress each week with an excel chart. Using VBA, how do I force the tick labels for the xlCategory axis to snap to each Monday in my data set? Is this possible? I know how to format the axes, but don't know how to tell it to begin with each Monday. Thanks!

I am aware there is an option to change the majorunit and minorunit, maybe I can use those somehow? This is what I have so far:

```
On Error Resume Next
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Delete
On Error GoTo 0

Set metricschart = sht.Shapes.AddChart.Chart

With metricschart
    .Parent.Name = "metricschart"
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Text = "Business Requirements Tested Over Time"
    .ChartTitle.Characters.Font.Size = 14
    .ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers
    .SetSourceData Source:=sht2.Range("A1:DA2")
    .Location where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:=sht.Name
    .Parent.Height = 325
    .Parent.Width = 600
    .Parent.Top = 70
    .Parent.Left = 350
    .Legend.LegendEntries(1).Delete
    .Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = sht2.Range("A1")
    .Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = sht2.Range("DA1")
    .Axes(xlCategory).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "m/d"
    .Axes(xlCategory).MajorUnit = vbMonday 'this doesn't work, shows way too many days
End With
```

The code above makes the axis like this (every 2 days):
[image]

This is what my data looks like: 
[image]

Comment: Can you show your sheet's data?

Comment: "Using VBA"... What code do you have so far and where are you stuck?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is to set the Category axis to timescale, determine a Monday for the starting value and just add the ticks at every seventh day.

```
Sub Test()
Dim cht As Chart
Dim ax As Axis

Set cht = Worksheets(1).ChartObjects(1).Chart
Set ax = cht.Axes(xlCategory)

With ax
    .CategoryType = xlTimeScale 'For dates
    .MajorUnit = 7 'Only 1 tick every 7 days
    .AxisBetweenCategories = False 'Tick exactly on the date, not between the values.
    .CrossesAt = 42975 'the integer value of the date you wish to be the first one. In this case 2017-08-28.
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Setting the category type, major unit to 7, and axis between categories did exactly what I needed. Earlier in the code I set the MinimumScale and MaximumScale so I am all set for when the axis begins. Thank you!